# Is it possible to load custom functions from LESS object and assign returned value to variable?

Tags: javascript, css, less

Is it possible to load custom functions from a LESS object?

I'm using `less.js` in my website (I need to update some vars values, I try using `modifyVars`).

I have this function:

```
// Get number of elements
getchilds(selector) {
    return jQuery(selector.value).length;
}
```

This is the code I try to use in LESS file:

```
@items = 1; // define a start value
.col-canvas {
    @items : getchilds('#eureka .col-canvas');
    & when (@items = 0){
        @items : 1;
    }
    width: ( 100% / @items );
}
```

Is it possible to assign a value returned from a function to a var?

Crunch 2 is showing me an error in this line:

```
width : ( 100% / @items );
```

Comment: While what you want is possible, it's much easier (and more proper) to set those elements width directly using jQuery (which you use anyway).

Comment: Either way (just to be able to vote for closing the Q a "too broad") - the error  in your snippet above is the assumption is that a javascript function defined elsewhere becomes available in Less - it is not the case of course (thus `getchilds('#eureka .col-canvas')` in your Less code has no effect and passes as-is since Less assumes it to be some unknown CSS function). As I mentioned above it *is* possible to create custom functions available in Less, but this requires a bit more efforts than above (you need to consult the docs as there different ways with different pros and cons).